# How to allow keras model predict function in multiple thread algorithm?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, python-multithreading

I'm trying to train a reinforcement learning(RL) agent on a custom environment. My RL agent is the stable baseline implementation of the DDPG algorithm. It uses multiple threads for training.
One of the arguments for this agent is an environment, which is implemented according to Open AI gym custom environment interface. My environment needs to be able to predict something using Keras(tenserflow) model. But doesnt allow this in thread setting.

Where the prediction look simply as follows : 
`label = np.argmax(model.predict(x.reshape(1,28,28,1)))`

The DDPG algorithm as follows :

```
from stable_baselines.ddpg.policies import MlpPolicy
from stable_baselines import DDPG


model_ddpg = DDPG(MlpPolicy, env, verbose=1, param_noise=param_noise, action_noise=action_noise)
model_ddpg.learn(total_timesteps=10)
```

And when running this getting following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1112             subfeed_t = self.graph.as_graph_element(
-> 1113                 subfeed, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
   1114           except Exception as e:

14 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3795     with self._lock:
-> 3796       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3797 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3874       if obj.graph is not self:
-> 3875         raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
   3876       return obj

ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_25:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-84-761d68b4955a> in <module>()
     13 
     14 model_ddpg = DDPG(MlpPolicy, env, verbose=1, param_noise=param_noise, action_noise=action_noise)
---> 15 model_ddpg.learn(total_timesteps=10)
     16 model_ddpg.save(root_dir + "ddpg_mnist_BA")
     17 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/stable_baselines/ddpg/ddpg.py in learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, replay_wrapper)
    892                                 unscaled_action = unscale_action(self.action_space, action)
    893 
--> 894                             new_obs, reward, done, info = self.env.step(unscaled_action)
    895 
    896                             self.num_timesteps += 1

<ipython-input-78-da82ecc928b0> in step(self, action)
     44 
     45   def step(self, action):
---> 46     self._BA_step(action)
     47 
     48     #observation update ,

<ipython-input-78-da82ecc928b0> in _BA_step(self, action)
    109     x_candidate = generate_sample(self.x_orig)
--> 110     label_candidate, dist_candidate = self._predict_sample(self.model,x_candidate, self.x_orig)


<ipython-input-78-da82ecc928b0> in _predict_sample(self, model, x, x_orig_normed)
    130     # nn = NeuralNetwork()
    131 
--> 132     lbl = np.argmax(model.predict(x.reshape(1,28,28,1)))
    133     print("predict is good")
    134     if x_orig_normed is None :

<ipython-input-81-79a6b7c803c8> in predict(self, x)
     29     self.model2._make_predict_function()
     30 
---> 31     y = self.model2.predict(x)
     32     return y

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1076           verbose=verbose,
   1077           steps=steps,
-> 1078           callbacks=callbacks)
   1079 
   1080   def reset_metrics(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    248     # Setup work for each epoch
    249     epoch_logs = {}
--> 250     model.reset_metrics()
    251     if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    252       callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch, epoch_logs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in reset_metrics(self)
   1082     if hasattr(self, 'metrics'):
   1083       for m in self.metrics:
-> 1084         m.reset_states()
   1085 
   1086     # Reset the state of loss metric wrappers.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in reset_states(self)
    197     when a metric is evaluated during training.
    198     """
--> 199     K.batch_set_value([(v, 0) for v in self.variables])
    200 
    201   @abc.abstractmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in batch_set_value(tuples)
   3069           assign_ops.append(assign_op)
   3070           feed_dict[assign_placeholder] = value
-> 3071         get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
   3072 
   3073 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    948     try:
    949       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 950                          run_metadata_ptr)
    951       if run_metadata:
    952         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1114           except Exception as e:
   1115             raise TypeError(
-> 1116                 'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
   1117 
   1118           if isinstance(subfeed_val, ops.Tensor):

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_25:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

So when passing this environment to the DDPG algorithm i'm getting problems because multiple threads will use the `model.predict()` keras function and this is not native supported for how i understand it.

I tried following solutions,

Implementing this as suggested on other keras threading stackoverflow topics was creating a graph and calling the `model2._make_predict_function()` function. None of this helped so far. I tried creating a seperate class and do the following :

```
import logging
class NeuralNetwork:

  def __init__(self):
    self.session = tf.Session()
    self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    # the folder in which the model and weights are stored
    self.model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model(root_dir+'model_mnist.h5')
    self.model2._make_predict_function()    
    # (target_label,target) = get_target(model)
    test = np.zeros(shape=(1,28,28,1))
    k = np.argmax(self.model2.predict(test))
    print(k)
    # for some reason in a flask app the graph/session needs to be used in the init else it hangs on other threads
    with self.graph.as_default():
      with self.session.as_default():
        print("init")
        logging.info("neural network initialised")


  def predict(self, x):
    self.model2._make_predict_function()
    with self.graph.as_default():
      with self.session.as_default():
        print("seems ok ?")
        y = self.model2.predict(x)
    return y
```

I'm not used to using thread related stuff. So i may be doing a lot wrong.
I also tried just creating a new keras model every time predict was needed this of course caused some performance issues. 
So how can i adjust this keras `model.predict()` function such that it works for threading?

**Tl;dr**: How to make keras `model.predict()` function able to work with algorithm that uses multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

I solved the problem by converting it to an estimator(tensorflow) model instead of keras(tensorflow) model. It allows multiple calls to the model without having to worry about thread safety it seems.